# Grid of squares coloring

Tags: combinatorics

> Imagine a grid of size n x n of squares, where each square is colored either white or black. Black spreads as follows: At each step, all the white squares which have at least two black neighbors (where neighbors must share a side – they can not be diagonal neighbors) become black. What is the minimum number of black squares needed at the beginning for the grid to be completely black at some point?
>   (This is from a puzzles Collection by Sophia Yakoubov, January 28, 2019, found in web.mit.edu website).

For $n = 3$, I found 3 and for $n = 4$, I found 7. I am trying to find a recursive relation but am not getting anywhere.

(This is not homework or anything; just challenging myself with nice puzzles!).

Any ideas?

Many thanks!

Comment: Can you not just color the diagonal black and after (n-1) steps everything is black?

Comment: This does not seem to satisfy the requirement that "neighbors must share a side".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think I saw this one in "[Coffee Time in Memphis](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0521693950)".  As Control's comment shows, $n$ squares are sufficient, since we can start with the diagonal.  To see that $n$ squares are necessary, note that the perimeter of the black area never increases.  When we color a square black, the two edges from its black neighbors become part of the interior, and are no longer on the perimeter.  The other two edges of the newly-colored square square may become part of the perimeter, if they weren't already, but the perimeter can't increase.

If it is to be $4n$ at the end, then we need at least $n$ black squares to start with.

Comment: Dear saulspatz, so does this mean that for $n=4$ we need 4 squares?? How?

Comment: Just start with the $4$ diagonal squares, as Control stated in his comment.

Comment: OK thank you. Can you explain a bit further what you wrote about the perimeter of the black area and $4n$? Thank you!

Comment: Certainly.  Done.